# Am I only supposed to have one Bootstrap 3 container?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm trying to figure out Bootstrap 3 and having lots of trouble. The Bootstrap 3 site says:

> Easily center a page's contents by wrapping its contents in a .container. Containers set
>   width at various media query breakpoints to match our grid system.
>
> Note that, due to padding and fixed widths, containers are not nestable by default.

The former line seems to support this, as I wouldn't want nested containers to re-set the width to more than the parent. That latter line makes me think that I should only have one container on a page (or siblings at most), regardless of fluid/normal/etc., without doing something "extra".

Is that correct?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You are correct in that you do not want to nest the .containers. However, there are plenty of cases where you would have multiple containers. For instance, if you want to have a full width element (screen width, not container width). This is perfectly fine:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="col-md-12">
    <p>Content</p>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="full-width-element">
  <p>Other content, stretching full width of the page</p>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div class="col-md-12">
    <p>Content</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Take a look at the examples on the Bootstrap site: http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#examples, they use multiple .containers as well.

So nesting container is not a good idea without modification or careful consideration. Using multiple containers is fine (otherwise it should have been an ID instead of a class as well)!

Comment: Yes, but these are siblings and not nested, which is what I was thinking. Thank you!

Comment: Yes, the docs say to not nest containers. Then they go ahead and nest containers in the examples (see: http://getbootstrap.com/examples/navbar/ ).