# Is it legal to use several containers on the same page in Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Is it legal to use several `container`s on the same page in Bootstrap?

I need to have a column with nested columns with its own sizes, not related to the parent's `container`.

Am I able to do so? Or am I limited to one `container` per page?

Comment: As far as i know, you can  use n number of container in one page..but if you are talking about nesting then you just to be careful with use of nested container, nothing else.

Comment: read more [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23062439/am-i-only-supposed-to-have-one-bootstrap-3-container)

Answer (score 10):

> Bootstrap requires a containing element to wrap site contents and
>   house our grid system. You may choose one of two containers to use in
>   your projects. Note that, due to padding and more, neither container
>   is nestable.

Read official doc [here](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#overview-container)

Comment: @FrozenHeart this could work https://codepen.io/carltondickson/pen/dgwOvZ
It is bootstrap 4 by the way

Answer (score 7):

Its is not illegal to use multiple containers. You can use as many as you want. e.g if you want to have multiple sections on a page with different background image or color, you can use sections and within each section you can use a container.

e.g

```
<section class="bg-1"><div class="container"></div></section>
<section class="bg-2"><div class="container"></div></section>
<section class="bg-3"><div class="container"></div></section>
```

In your case, you can use a fluid container and define your own sized columns. This way you will have container and your own layout divs.

Hope this helps.

Comment: You can use bootstrap grids for that.  This will help : http://codepen.io/hunzaboy/pen/ObzPyd

Answer (score 3):

Quoted from Bootstrap: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#overview-container

> Bootstrap requires a containing element to wrap site contents and house our grid system. You may choose one of two containers to use in your projects. Note that, due to padding and more, neither container is nestable.

I think the grid is the best solution for this.

Comment: What do you mean by grid? Flex grid?

Comment: The Grid system provided by bootstrap: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid

Comment: I thought that bootstrap's grid system is that `container`s' stuff

Comment: You should carefully read the bootstrap documentation. It's easy to read and will help you to better understand the difference between `.container` and the grid.

Comment: @DerAlex - I don't see the difference, even after carefully reading. To me, the grid-system gets nested inside either of the containers available, which basically limits the width of our inside grid so that it gets calculated properly. So, the grid-system it self and the outer container go hand-in-hand, as neither of them is a good use without the other. Then again, if that's correct and you want to differentiate on that level, don't mind my comment :D

Comment: @FrozenHeart https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/27534/ This would be one example of nesting the rows/columns properly and make use of the grid :) (To make the left-part the same height as the right one, you will need additional css.)